# Confusion about the de-referencing of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm confused about the de-referencing of pointers, if I've the below code snippet:

```
char str[]="ABC";
char *a=str;
```

Then what does a+1 refer to?

Is it B or BC as a whole?

This confusion has dawned in me because when I give:

```
cout<<a+1;
```

It gives me BC instead of B, why is it like that?

If I've a function to swap values and if it takes in arguments like:

```
void swap((a+1),(a+2))
```

How will the above function work out?
Will it swap B with C?

Comment: It points to `B`. But `B` is followed by `C` so, it's down to how you want to visualize it for your given purpose.

Comment: Related: [With arrays, why is it the case that a\[5\] == 5\[a\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: That's an odd swap function. You should read its documentation, or the definition to find out what it does.

Comment: `Will it swap B with C?` Yes, it should swap B and C. Hint: could use `std::iter_swap` for it: https://ideone.com/SYAVVS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then what does a+1 refer to?

`a` points to the first element of the array `str`. The value of the first character is `'A'`. The result of `a + 1` expression is a pointer to the next element of `str` after the one that `a` points to. The next element is the character with the value `'B`'.

> This confusion has dawned in me because when I give:
>
> ```
> cout<<a+1;
> ```
>
> It gives me BC instead of B, why is it like that?

This is because when you insert a pointer to a character into a character stream (such as `std::cout`), it is assumed to point to a character in an array (as it does in this case), and the behaviour is to stream all characters in that array until the null  termination character (`\0`) is reached.

So, just like when you insert the pointer that points to `A` and all characters starting from `A` until the null termination character are printed (`ABC`), similarly when you pass the pointer that points to `B` then all characters starting from `B` are printed (`BC`).

You can dereference the pointer to insert just that one character, if that is your intention:

```
std::cout << *a;       // A
std::cout << *(a + 1); // B
```

or

```
std::cout << a[0]; // A
std::cout << a[1]; // B
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's your pointer, `a`, pointing to the start of the string "ABC" (note the \0 at the end represents the implicit NUL-terminator byte):

```
ABC\0
^
|
a
```

Here's what it looks like after you add one to `a`:

```
ABC\0
 ^
 |
 a
```

Note that `a` is now pointing to the next entry in the char-array.  cout will print chars until it reaches the NUL-terminator byte at the end of the array, so if you do a `cout<<(a+1)` it will print "BC".

Answer (score 2):

The difference between pointing to an element, and pointing to the beginning of a range of elements depends entirely on how you use that pointer. It's not an intrinsic property of the pointer. Whether `a+1` refers to `'B'` or `"BC"` depends on what you do with the pointer. It just so happens that `std::cout` treats all `char` pointers as pointers to C strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[]="ABC";
char *a=str;
```

`a` is char pointer and it's points to `str` as below

```
    --------------------
   |  A  |  B  C  | \0  |
    ----------------------
  0x100   0x101 ... .. (lets say 0x100  is the base address of str)
  str
  a
```

If you prints

```
cout<<a<<endl;/* it starts from 0x100 location and prints upto NULL */
```

and

```
/* a+1 == 0x100 + 1x1  == 0x101 */
cout<<a+1<<endl; /* a+1 means it starts printing from 0x101 location upto NULL character so it prints BC*/
```

Edit :

```
void swap((a+1),(a+2))
```

*How will the above function work out? Will it swap B with C? =>* yes it will swap B and C, depends upon swap function logic.